# Rotating Div from bottom to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I want to change the transition of my sliding texts. The current effect is a fade in and fade out, but I would like the `.quotes` to slide or scroll to top then the next block of `.quotes` will follow. Something like a rotating div but the transition is to top. I tried `slideTop()` but it loos different from what I want. Here's my current code and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wTtH/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="quotes">
<h3 class="heading green">GoScRUB orks Much Faster than a scrub brush on tough build-up</h3>
<h3 class="heading green">GoScRUB aves Money – it is about 1/10 the cost of a scrub rush</h3>
</div>

<div class="quotes">
<h3>GoScRUB s Better for the Environment than a scrub brush – less waste</h3>
<h3>GoScRUB s More Effective than a scrub brush – it lifts and peels off the debris</h3>
</div>

<div class="quotes">
<h3 class="heading green">GoScRUB Cleans Easily and is much more sanitary than a scrub brush</h3>
<h3 class="heading green">GoScRUB Lasts 10x Longer than a scrub brush (or more)</h3>
<h3 class="heading green">GoScRUB llows your Scrub Pads to Last Much Longer</h3>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
(function() {
    var quotes = jQuery(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;
    function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
    .fadeIn(2000)
    .delay(2000)
    .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

    })();
```

**CSS:**

```
.quotes h3{
padding-left:20px;
line-height: 52px;
margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.quotes {display: none;}

.heading-slide h3{
font-size:34px;
}
```

Comment: You need a parent container to work as a mask with `overflow:hidden` when you animate the quotes to top.

Comment: Thanks, can you show it to me using my jsfiddle? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, the approach I'd take is to use a parent `div` that will hide the bottom children and will only show one quote at a time. When a quote is displayed and animates to top (outside of parent), it is appended at the end of the parent.

**[Here's the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qy53j/3/)**. *(It's not optimized but you get the basic idea)*

Answer (score 0):

is this you want :

```
(function() {
    var quotes = jQuery(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;
    function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
    .slideDown(1000)
    .delay(4000)
    .slideUp(1000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

    })();
```

Comment: I appreciate that, but I already tried that but that's not what I want, I want the div to scroll up.

Answer (score 0):

basically what you need is a vertical carousel .

there are many ways in witch you can achieve what you want . one them is: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

this should be done in 2 steps:

1. cycle between items  - done in JS
2. add the scrolling animation - done in CSS

first part you can take as is from twitter bootstrap (or any other cycle-ing plugin)

for the second part . you will need to change some of the CSS .

```
.carousel-inner > .active {
    left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .next {
    left: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .prev {
    left: -100%;
}
```

into

```
.carousel-inner > .active {
    top: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .next {
    top: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .prev {
    top: -100%;
}
```

what i did was to take all references to left/right and change them to top/bottom